# How to make url in footnote clickable?

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, urls

How to make url in footnote clickable?

Currently I have:

```
\paragraph{Some text \protect\footnote{xyz available at \protect\url{https://someplace.org}}}
```

The footnote appears just fine but nothing happens when I click the url.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you added `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the preamble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you all for such quick replies! @TorbjørnT. was spot on, I thought I had the package but I didn't. I now have the blue boxes around the url in the pdf but if I open the pdf in a viewer it does not open a link in my browser.

Comment: @Jubobs I thought it was such a small problem it wouldn't need one. I'll try and add one now.

Comment: @kotoko It's pretty much always best to add an MWE in the question, because it indicates the context of your problem to people willing to help you. There may be several things preventing links in footnotes (loaded packages, macro redefinitions, etc.), but an MWE would tell us exactly what happens in your code before the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the package `hyperref` and call the url by `\url{https://someplace.org}`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

The paragraph.\footnote{has a footnote with and url \url{https://someplace.org}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It my redirect problem mentioned earlier should with the system because this pdf does not redirect on click either. Are you able to open a tab on the browser when you click on the blue box?

Comment: @kotoko This may be a PDF-viewer-depedent issue. For instance, Mac OS X Preview doesn't follow hyperlinks in PDF, whereas Acrobat Reader would.

Comment: These days, Mac OS X Preview very well follows any hyperlinks in PDF documents, including also going back to the link's origin (if it was a doc-internal link).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing extra package required. I just found it I hope it will help someone.

```
\footnote{\href {http://www.google.com}{www.facebook.com}}.
```

or for one website.

```
\footnote{\href {http://www.google.com}}.
```

Comment: This actually requires `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: I am using https://www.overleaf.com/ and I am using it without any package. obviously I tested it before posting.

Comment: overleaf is a specific environment that must then be loading the package for you.